# SQL Server Date to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm new to using SQL Server 2012 and the `Date` type in my C# applications and am curious about the conversion to `DateTime`. I have a DBML file representing my table and a type that has a server data type of `Date` and a type of `DateTime`. I'm trying to do a simple comparison between the current day and the value in my table:

```
if (adc.HolidaySchedules.FirstOrDefault(d => ((DateTime)d.HolidayDate).Date.AddDays(-1) == DateTime.Today.Date) != null)
```

It throws the following `SqlException`

```
The datepart millisecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.
```

I'm curious as to why I'm getting this particular exception when I'm only accessing the `Date` and what I should be doing, explicitly or otherwise, to handle this type of conversion. I would have thought I could call `AddDays()` on a `Date`.

Comment: i would suggest to use [SqlMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform operation on server : `SqlMethods.DateDiffYear(o.ModifiedDate, DateTime.Now) > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you transforming *each* value in column `HolidayDate` instead of passing the correct parameter?

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var item = adc.HolidaySchedules.FirstOrDefault(d => d.HolidayDate == date);
if(item != null)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work. I'm more curious as to why it doesn't work on the HolidayDate value though if anyone has anything.

Comment: Well, you can fire SqlServer Profiler to see the actual sql query sent to the database.